# How to find which key was pressed

Tags: javascript

I created textfield using `<input>` tag.If you enter any character on textfield. I want to print that character in console.

I searched in google,everyone suggesting jQuery.I am learning Javascript so without completing Javascipt course I don't want to switch jQuery.

Comment: why you don't want to use jquery? is a powerfull tool in javascript

Comment: Although jQuery is a Javascript library, it is actually simpler and in many ways better to learn jQuery first rather than worry about pure Javascript. jQuery's main reason for existence is that Javascript is inconsistent across different browsers, and jQuery makes it consistent across browsers. In addition, jQuery makes many tasks simpler and easier to do than in pure Javascript.

Comment: Have a look at the [`onkeypress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onkeypress) JavaScript function.

Comment: @HamzaKubba, I would disagree. I think the OP should learn JScript before jumping into jQuery. Also you argument of Javascript being inconsistent across browsers does not hold true with the launch of ie9 and ie10. Plus adding the overhead of using jQuery for a simple task is an overkill.

Comment: Yes, what I said does hold true even with the launch of IE9 and IE10. Look at the examples below for immediate examples (e.g. `if(window.event){ // IE` from Dilantha's answer). jQuery being 'overkill' is entirely moot considering he's trying to learn, and jQuery is super light and insignificant on any modern machine/browser. I think the OP should learn Javascript, sure, but my point is he/she should not avoid jQuery because it somehow slows down the learning of Javascript... jQuery makes Javascript code cleaner, and cleaner code is easier to read and learn from.

Comment: @HamzaKubba,@X-Pippes I will learn `Jquery`,before that I want to learn basics of `jScript`.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple implementation which doesn't require any jquery at all. 
You just need to call the following function on keyup

```
function printKey(evt) {
    var keyCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
    console.log(keyCode);
}
```

You can see it in action here
http://jsbin.com/ikeVAbA/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: It's not actually wrong, but is the way JavaScript interpret things.
For JavaScript, A/a have same key stroke of 65. It additionally captures Shift (16) or CapsLock (20). So if you need to show upper case or lower case letter, check for key codes of these two keys.

Answer (score 5):

```
function myKeyPress(e){

            var keynum;

            if(window.event){ // IE                 
                keynum = e.keyCode;
            }else
                if(e.which){ // Netscape/Firefox/Opera                  
                    keynum = e.which;
                 }
            alert(String.fromCharCode(keynum));
        }
```

and your input

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return myKeyPress(event)" />
```

You can find the list of key code [here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes). With that you can identify which key is being pressed

Comment: @Dilantha you passed `event` as a argument to `myKeyPress()`. what is event.If you know any tutorials about this can you provide me.Also confirm me your function won't work in `Google chrome`.

Comment: We are passing the Dom event as a parameter to myKeyPress. More about Dom events in javascript http://www.pradosoft.com/demos/quickstart/?page=Advanced.Scripts2

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return getCode(e)" />

function getCode(evt){
 var cc = (evt.charCode) ? evt.charCode : ((evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode);
 alert(String.fromCharCode(cc));
}
```